# Application received signal SIGSEGV

Tags: ios, crash

Application received signal SIGSEGV

```
(null)
((
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001850a2da4 <redacted> + 252
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000018425c5ec objc_exception_throw + 56
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001850a2c6c <redacted> + 0
 3   rrdSJ                               -[UMAnalyticsConfig init] (in rrdSJ) + 120 rrdSJ + 3089900
 4   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x0000000184cc4b48 _sigtramp + 36
 5   CoreGraphics                        0x0000000186a48548 CGDataProviderRetainBytePtr + 216
 6   QuartzCore                          0x0000000189116c20 <redacted> + 196
 7   QuartzCore                          0x0000000189114e58 <redacted> + 868
 8   QuartzCore                          0x00000001891179e0 <redacted> + 472
 9   QuartzCore                          0x0000000189117da4 <redacted> + 20
 10  QuartzCore                          0x0000000189227b0c <redacted> + 420
 11  QuartzCore                          0x0000000189189ba0 <redacted> + 576
 12  QuartzCore                          0x00000001891b15d0 <redacted> + 580
 13  QuartzCore                          0x00000001891b2450 <redacted> + 92
 14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000018504a910 <redacted> + 32
 15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185048238 <redacted> + 412
 16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185048884 <redacted> + 1436
 17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000184f68da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
 18  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000186f4b020 GSEventRunModal + 100
 19  UIKit                               0x000000018ef4978c UIApplicationMain + 236
 20  rrdSJ                               -[DWCustomizeTableView reloadData] (in rrdSJ) (DWCustomizeTableView.m:89) rrdSJ + 675572
 21  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001849f9fc0 <redacted> + 4
)

dSYM UUID: E7CA6480-AD76-3EE3-A310-FB4402C17B17
CPU Type: arm64
Slide Address: 0x0000000100000000
Binary Image: rrdSJ
Base Address: 0x0000000102fb0000
```

---

> DWCustomizeTableView.m:89
>       viewSeparatorLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _borderWidth, bgView.height)];

I catched this exception.
Could anybody give me some suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Please add more detail of the context and code you are running?

Comment: I already locationed my code (DWCustomizeTableView.m:89), but just a simple view init.